# Avoid jumping figures and align them in beamer

Tags: beamer

I'm trying to make a slide with a citation at the bottom for a couple of the slides and no citation for the first.
Unfortunatly all my attempts have been futile. I've read the most popular threads here on SE on stopping jumping frames in beamer, but I have not been able to successfully apply them (trying both `overprint` and `overlayarea` as well as with and w/o `columns`).

### Goal:

My goal is to have the figures aligned at the center of each column.
I.e., for the first and second slide both figures are aligned center, and for the last slide, the two figures in the left column are stacked at the center.

### Current issues:

Currently, the images jumps between slides one and two, and on the third slide the images to the left do not center.
The image to the left do not jump between slides 2-3 though.
If I try to move the `\blfootnote{...}` command inside the `overlayarea` it adds an `a` to the frame (seems to be due to the . The images stops to jump, though. On the other hand, the left column does not align at the center.

### MWE:

```
\documentclass[usenames,dvipsnames]{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\mode<presentation>{}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\setbeamercovered{invisible}
\setbeamercovered{%
    still covered={\opaqueness<1->{0}},
    again covered={\opaqueness<1->{15}}
}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
    \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
    \endgroup
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[c]
        \frametitle{frametitle}
        \only<2-3>{
            \blfootnote{
                A author and year
            }
        }
        \begin{columns}
            \column{.49\linewidth}
            \begin{overlayarea}{\linewidth}{.75\textheight}
                \only<1>{
                    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
                }\only<2>{
                    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
                }\only<3>{
                    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
                        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=.25\textheight]{example-image}\\
                        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=.25\textheight]{example-image}
                    \end{minipage}
                }
            \end{overlayarea}
            \column{.49\linewidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
            \vfill
        \end{columns}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the columns inside the `overlayarea` environment.

*Edit*: Add `\only<1>{\vspace*{2.95mm}}` to add the "jump" on slide 1.

```
\documentclass[usenames,dvipsnames]{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\mode<presentation>{}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\setbeamercovered{invisible}
\setbeamercovered{%
    still covered={\opaqueness<1->{0}},
    again covered={\opaqueness<1->{15}}
}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
    \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
    \endgroup
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[c]
        \frametitle{frametitle}
        \only<1>{\vspace*{2.95mm}}
        \only<2-3>{
            \blfootnote{
                A author and year
            }
        }
        \begin{overlayarea}{\linewidth}{.75\textheight}
                \only<1>{
                    \begin{columns}[c]
                        \column{.49\linewidth}
                        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
                    \column{.49\linewidth}
                        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
                    \end{columns}
                }\only<2>{
                    \begin{columns}[c]
                    \column{.49\linewidth}
                        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
                    \column{.49\linewidth}
                        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
                    \end{columns}
                }\only<3>{
                    \begin{columns}[c]
                        \column{.49\linewidth}
                            \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
                                \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=.25\textheight]{example-image}\\
                                \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=.25\textheight]{example-image}
                            \end{minipage}
                        \column{.49\linewidth}
                            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
                    \end{columns}
                }
            \vfill
        \end{overlayarea}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. Far better than mine, but the figures still jump between slide 1 and 2 =/.

Comment: What do you mean by "jump"?. Figures appear where you put them, as far as I can see.

Comment: For me, the figures goes down when I change from slide 1 to 2 using your example.

Comment: You can add the "jump" on the first slide by adding `\only<1>{\vspace*{2.95mm}}` before the `overlayarea`, or do the opposite (negative space to remove the jump) on the slides 2 and 3.

Comment: Oh right, thank you so much! Stupid of me to not think of that...

Comment: I edited the post to provide a complete answer. Glad to help!